German federal budget data for 2018 - 2024?
Can anyone point me to data on the German federal budget for 2018 - 2024,
downloadable .csv or .xml files ?
https://www.bundeshaushalt.de/DE/Bundeshaushalt-digital/bundeshaushalt-digital.html
has bar plots which one can click on for each year, and breakdowns one can cut-paste, e.g.
      Einzelplan-Betrag-(in-Tausend-Euro)      Anteil

Bundesministerium-für-Arbeit-und-Soziales 171.712.528 37,52%
       Bundesministerium-der-Verteidigung  51.176.635 11,18%
                             Bundesschuld  39.203.179  8,57%
                                      ...

but I don't see "download csv" -- what you see is all you get.
A quick plot of the yearly totals (misleading in several ways):


A paper
under fdp.de
by the former finance minister Lindner
has a graph that looks close to this (without debt), but no .csv, no breakdown.
(He was fired on 6 November; maybe if his plots had been more convincing, all along ... :)

Isn't a budget by definition what was planned, not what was actually spent?

@gerrit, yes, you're right. But in looking at data over say 2018 - 2024,
it's common to take spending for previous years, and the budget forecast for the current year.

This should be what you are looking for but it does not cover 2024
https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/157795/umfrage/entwicklung-der-ausgaben-des-bundes-seit-1969/
and then there is this for 2024-2027
https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/226116/umfrage/finanzplan-des-bundes/
If you are looking for more detailed spendings data, take a look here
https://de.statista.com/themen/12513/bundeshaushalt/#statisticChapter
Here is some interesting article where you have some forecasting data, but nothing downloadable https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Monatsberichte/Ausgabe/2024/09/Inhalte/Kapitel-3-Analysen/3-1-staatssekretaer-reuter-bundeshaushalt-2025.html

Thanks. Unfortunately, statista.com requires an account, and the €0 account doesn't work for this. (Bytheway, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_federal_budget has some pretty good Infographics for 2023: debt and predicted budget deficits, wow.)
